# BLE 4.2 RN4870 Command mode confih?guration

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

While working on one RN4870 modules, I came across this problem. How do you set the module into command mode when it boots? What is the command set to get it connected to another module automatically onces it boots.

I tried to make a script in Python to do this.

```
    $$$
    +
    LB
    C,0,82938DFF897 (C, public/random, address)
```

Both of them have been bonded and upon boot I have to connect through UART and go to command mode and try C2/C3 to connect one another. Is there a GPIO configuration to do the same? I'm kinda new to this module any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your command should be ok
$$$ enter command mode
You need a delay to enter in command mode
LB ( I think you don't need the list of bonded device)
C,0,MAC ADDRESS is correct to connect to the remote bluetooth device.
I use then CI to start client operation
LC to read all the service and chracteristics
CHR Handle to read
CHW Handle to write

I hope  is useful
Best Regards